# Is there a way to have "onPress" and "onLongPress" on same "Button/TouchableOpacity"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I am wondering if there is a way to have onPress and onLongPress on the same button/TouchableOpacity, in react-native with javascript,
If so how do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#props), you can add an `onPress` and `onLongPress` props.

For the record, TouchableOpacity inherits all the props available on TouchableWithoutFeedback.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => { console.log("onPress") }}
  onLongPress={() => { console.log("onLongPress") }}
>
   ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```